# how do I merge two UIViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

i'm not really sure if my title is really appropriate. But i'm trying to make a app that lets users draw on the screen with multitouch. If more then one touch is on the screen it will alloc custom UIview that performs all drawing and add that to the view. The problem occurs if more then 6 touches is down, then it will start too lag and fps will drop. To fix this I could make it so all drawing is made on the same view. However, this nullifies the one of the features of my app which the ability to hide some views by setting alpha to 0. So is there any way to "merge" the drawing made in these views into a separate view of some kind (layer,uiimageview or uiview) to fix the fps problems?

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGImageRef cacheImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cacheContext);

     CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, cacheImage);
    CGImageRelease(cacheImage);
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but `UIView`s see rather heavyweight.  How are you capturing the user gestures?  If they are paths or points, how about wrapping them in custom classes with a `hidden` attribute to replace the view alpha approach?

Comment: You could try storing a snapshot of the view in your update loop, and loading it under new content on the next frame. (UIView has a snapshot method). That could be heavy, too, though; but, something to try. Another thing to keep in mind is that using the alpha channel slows down rendering -- you *definitely* don't want to hide by setting alpha to 0. Use the .hidden property instead.

Comment: That snapshot idea seems nice. But, it looks like it only works for views what are visible, so whats the purpose then of using it here?